# How do I fetch only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, rest

I want to fetch a name and a photo from a rest API called "randomuserAPI", to add to some kind of card in my website, but it just keeps fetching again and again in a loop, and never stops at one (I just want one random number and photo but it just keeps updating those things all the time).

This is my Course element, in which the card is created with the fetched data, which is fetched inside a function somewhere else.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {getUser} from '../library/getUsers.js'


const Course = ({author}) => { 

    const [userInfo, changeUserInfo] = useState('User')
    const [userPhoto, changeUserPhoto] = useState('https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png')

    getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto)

    return(
        <div className="course">
            <h4>{userInfo}</h4>
            <p>{author}</p>
            <img src={userPhoto} width="200px" height="200px" alt=""></img>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Course;
```

And this is the function which fetches the API:

```
export async function getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto){

    await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=3')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((user) => {
        changeUserInfo(`${user.results[0].name.first} ${user.results[0].name.first}`)
        changeUserPhoto(user.results[0].picture.large)
    })
}
```

I don´t know if anything can be wrong here, but here's the App element:

```
import React from 'react';
import Course from './elements/course';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Course 
        author = 'Tato Gucci'
      />  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the results parameter in the url? That defines how many users you want. Its currently set to results=3 which should give you three users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue :**

```
render -> getUser -> setting State -> re-render -> getUser .....
```

```
const Course = ({author}) => { 

    const [userInfo, changeUserInfo] = useState('User')
    const [userPhoto, changeUserPhoto] = useState('https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png')

    //------------- ISSUE -------------
    // `getUser` get called when ever component get rendered
    // and it is setting up state , so it is causing re-rendering
    // so it's kind of infinte loop 
    // render -> getUser -> setState -> re-render .....
    getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto)'

    return(
        <div className="course">
            <h4>{userInfo}</h4>
            <p>{author}</p>
            <img src={userPhoto} width="200px" height="200px" alt=""></img>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

**Solution :**

You can put `getUser` inside `useEffect` : so it will get called only when component get mounts

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto)
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getUser` without any restriction will cause an infinity loop (component `Course` render > call `getUser` > change `userInfo` and `userPhoto` > trigger render `Course` > call `getUser` again > ...)

You have to put your function that cause side effect (fetch API) into `useEffect` hook, in this context is  `getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto)` function.

```
useEffect = (() => {
   getUser(changeUserInfo, changeUserPhoto)
}, [])
```

The empty array is make sure `getUser` function just run only once time.

You should read more about [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns as far as I understood are:
You want a single result from the API.
You need the result to be constant and must not change.

Instead of using `https://randomuser.me/api?results=3` use `https://randomuser.me/api?results=1`
You were fetching 3 results and expecting a single result.

To make the result constant you need to store the fetched result in database and check the data exist or not before fetching. You only need to fetch data if its not exist in your database.