# How can I make my fetch to be called only once inside a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I am fetching an object and extracting a url from it.

However, my console.log is being logged 8 times. Where is my mistake?

```
import React from 'react';
// import Card from './Card';

function Gameboard() {
  let url = '';
  const [card, setCard] = React.useState('kk');
  const [cardUrl, setCardUrl] = React.useState('');

  fetch('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards/base1-1', {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'X-Api-key': 'myapi',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data.images.large);
      setCardUrl(data.data.images.large);
    });
  return <div>{cardUrl}</div>;
  // <Card key={data.number} url={data.images.large} />;
}
export default Gameboard;
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I fetch only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966996/how-do-i-fetch-only-once)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your fetch code inside a useEffect with [] as the dependency array so it only triggers once

```
import React from 'react';

function Gameboard() {
  let url = '';
  const [card, setCard] = React.useState('kk');
  const [cardUrl, setCardUrl] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards/base1-1', {
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'X-Api-key': 'myapi',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data.images.large);
        setCardUrl(data.data.images.large);
      });
  }, []}
  return <div>{cardUrl}</div>;
  // <Card key={data.number} url={data.images.large} />;
}
export default Gameboard;
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before posting an answer (but props for mentioning the empty dependency array)

Comment: What if I need to change the url later on?